# Querying non imported objects from the User Profile Service

Tags: user-profile

I want to customize the My Site Deletion Timer Job. For this I have to query the profiles which were not imported in the last synchronization.

There is a user **Domain\User_A** which I can see in the **Profiles Missing from Import** view.

According to some blog posts the query

```
$ups = Get-SPServiceApplication | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service Application" }
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true
```

should print

```
These objects will be marked for deletion.
User Domain\User_A
```

in the PowerShell console. But in my test on two different SharePoint 2010 farms I only see

```
These objects will be marked for deletion.
```

printed in the PowerShell window.

Beside the query above is there any other way to query non imported objects from the profile store?

Comment: That command return just the users that have never been imported